# VBA unique values count along with sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am trying to go through each sheet in my workbook and print the name of the sheet along with each of the unique items and a count of them. But I am getting an error, please help.
This is a broad example of the result I am trying to achieve, right now I have the commented out.

"Sheet1"    Dan       2
"Sheet1"    Bob       23
"Sheet1"    Mark      1
"Sheet2"    Ban       3
"Sheet2"    Dan       2

I get an error with this line:

> ```
> Sheets("Summary").Range(NextRowB).Resize(dict.Count - 1, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
> ```

```
    Sub summaryReport()

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dim varray As Variant, element As Variant

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets


        varray = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Value


        'Generate unique list and count
         For Each element In varray

        If dict.exists(element) Then
            dict.Item(element) = dict.Item(element) + 1
        Else
            dict.Add element, 1
        End If

    Next

    NextRowB = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    NextRowC = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheets("Summary").Range(NextRowB).Resize(dict.Count - 1, 1).Value=ActiveSheet.Name
    Sheets("Summary").Range(NextRowC).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = _WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys)
    'Sheets("Summary").Range("D3").Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = _
    WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.items)

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: `NextRowB` returns a number so `Range(NextRowB)` is incorrect. Perhaps `Range("B" & NextRowB)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a dictionary this code uses a temporary sheet and formula.
The names are copied from each sheet, the duplicates removed and then a `COUNTIF` formula is applied to make the count.
The final figures are then copied and the values pasted into column A of the temporary sheet.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim tmpSht As Worksheet
    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim rTmpLastCell As Range
    Dim rLastCalculatedCell As Range

    'Add a temporary sheet to do calculations and store the list to be printed.
    Set tmpSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
   'Comment out the line above, and uncomment the next two lines
   'to print exclusively to the "Summary" sheet.
   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
   'Set tmpSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
   'tmpSht.Cells.ClearContents

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        With wrkSht
            'Decide what to do with the sheet based on its name.
            Select Case .Name

                Case tmpSht.Name
                    'Do nothing
                Case Else 'Process sheet.

                    Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)
                    'tmpSht.Columns(4).Resize(, 3).ClearContents

                    'Copy names to temp sheet and remove duplicates.
                    .Range(.Cells(1, 2), rLastCell).Copy Destination:=tmpSht.Cells(1, 5)
                    tmpSht.Columns(5).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

                    'Calculate how many names appear on the sheet and place sheet name
                    'to left of people names.
                    Set rTmpLastCell = tmpSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)
                    tmpSht.Range(tmpSht.Cells(1, 5), rTmpLastCell).Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                        "=COUNTIF('" & wrkSht.Name & "'!R1C2:R" & rLastCell.Row & "C2,RC[-1])"
                    tmpSht.Range(tmpSht.Cells(1, 5), rTmpLastCell).Offset(, -1) = wrkSht.Name

                    'Find end of list to be printed.
                    Set rLastCalculatedCell = tmpSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

                    'Copy columns D:F which contain the sheet name, person name and count.
                    'Paste at the end of column A:C
                    tmpSht.Range(tmpSht.Cells(1, 4), rTmpLastCell).Resize(, 3).Copy
                    rLastCalculatedCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                    'Clear columns D:F
                    tmpSht.Columns(4).Resize(, 3).ClearContents

            End Select

        End With

    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked!, I was also wondering if it would be possible to leave a formula on the existing sheet in column D and E or after the macro runs.  
  
  
  
  
  
 =IF(B7="","",COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&B7&"'!"&"B:B"),'Summary (2)'!C7,INDIRECT("'"&B7&"'!"&"Q:Q"),"<=5"))

Comment: I am very new to VBA sorry if it is a dumb question!

Comment: There's no such thing as a dumb question. When you say the _existing_ sheet do you mean the Summary sheet? What does the formula do? I can't check it at the moment & may not be able to reply for another 12 hours.

Comment: I figured it out Darren thanks for all the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

My code stores an ArrayList for each key in the Dictionary to hold the list of Worksheet names associated with the key.  After all the data has been gathered it uses another ArrayList to store an array for each key, `Array(Worksheet Name, Key Value, Count)`.  It extracts the data from that ArrayList to an Array which is written to the Summary Worksheet.

```
Sub SummaryReport()
    Dim n As Long
    Dim dict As Object, list As Object, Target As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim key As Variant, keyWSName As Variant, data As Variant

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            If Not .Name = "Summary" Then
                Set Target = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                If Not Target Is Nothing Then
                    For n = 1 To Target.Count
                        key = Target.Cells(1)
                        If Trim(key) <> "" Then
                            If Not dict.exists(key) Then
                                dict.Add key, CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
                            End If
                            dict(key).Add ws.Name
                        End If
                    Next

                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For Each key In dict
        For Each keyWSName In dict(key)
            list.Add Array(keyWSName, key, dict(key).Count)
        Next
    Next

    ReDim data(1 To list.Count, 1 To 3)
    For n = 0 To list.Count - 1
        data(n + 1, 1) = list(n)(0)
        data(n + 1, 2) = list(n)(1)
        data(n + 1, 3) = list(n)(2)
    Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
        .Columns("B:D").ClearContents
        .Range("B2:D2").Resize(list.Count).Value = data
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello TinMan, Thank you for your help but I always get this problem (note I am new to VBA). With this line: (and a few others that have .Range)                                                                                                
For Each key In .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value                                                                      I get the error application defined or object defined error. Do you know how do fix this?

Comment: Thanks again TinMan, but I am getting another error (sorry I'm really new to VBA and I am not good at debugging). For Each key In Target.Value --> I get a type mismatch error

Comment: For Each key In Target.Value, this is the exact line of error, in each sheet there are text values for customer names.

Comment: the pages have varying amounts of customer names, till the last row I believe.

Comment: I get the value 1